# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_Moment'

Tags: python, flask

Why do i get an error when i try to import a flask extension but when i run the app i get the ModuleNotFoundError

i am running flask version`Flask== 0.12.2`

this is the app

```
from flask import Flask,request,render_template,send_from_directory
from flask_moment import Moment

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

i then run `py -3 app.py` using my virtual environment and these are the results

```
(venv1) PS D:\2. Design\Web\FlaskApp\apps\tut1> py -3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_moment import Moment
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_moment'
(venv1) PS D:\2. Design\Web\FlaskApp\apps\tut1>
```

maybe just to show you the modules i have installed `pip freeze` returns

```
(venv1) PS D:\2. Design\Web\FlaskApp\apps\tut1> pip freeze
click==6.7
dominate==2.3.1
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-Moment==0.6.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
visitor==0.1.3
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Comment: Can you share the log of `pip3 freeze` if it's possible?

Comment: `from flask_moment import Moment`

Comment: it is included in the question

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.

It has to do with me using VS code powershell to install the packages

When I did a `pip freeze` in cmd shell I discovered the packages were not installed so I reinstalled everything using cmd.exe shell